# How can I Block Attachments where file format is JPG, PNG using Trigger in lightning experience?

Tags: salesforce1-app, lightning, lightning-experience

I want to block the upload of attachments having file types png,jpg using trigger in Lightning Experience,

Thanks,
Karthi

Answer (score 2):

This is a scenario I ran smack into yesterday afternoon. As Keith described in his answer, LEx treats uploads from the standard Notes & Attachments list as "Files". This means that any trigger code you have on the Attachment object won't fire. In our case, we welcome image Attachments, but use a third-party API to convert them to PDF format after they've been inserted.

Luckily, we know that Salesforce uses Content for storage of its Files, allowing users to update the same File with subsequent versions. As such, it is storing the File data in the `ContentVersion` object behind the scenes. As I said I ran into this problem yesterday so I don't have a complete solution in place, but we can add a trigger to this object and leverage its fields on newly-inserted records to determine whether or not a File is an image.

The fields are a bit different than what you're used to on the Attachment object, I'd imagine. A few notes on the differences:

- Content likes to clean up filenames (e.g. `photo001.jpg` becomes `photo001` when displayed in the UI. To get the original filename, use the `ContentVersion.PathOnClient` field.
- If you'd rather not have to parse out the file extension on your own, you can leverage the `ContentVersion.FileExtension` field.
- Rather than `Attachment.ContentType`, Salesforce attempts to clean up the mimetype for you, which is stored in the `ContentVersion.FileType` field. Rather than seeing `image/bmp` here, you'll just see `BMP`.

So you should be able to add some quick trigger logic and throw an error if any image is uploaded; this does seem a bit strict, however, since this change would apply to all `ContentVersion` records. You may need to come up with a way to determine which File records should be prevented from being uploaded; e.g. you could check the parent record of the File being inserted (which would mean doing some digging in the `ContentVersion.ContentDocumentId` lookup). Otherwise, this would most likely prevent any images from being added to Chatter.

For my use case...rather than overwriting the `Attachment.Body` field with the results of a webservice callout, I'll most likely need to insert a new `ContentVersion` record.

**Edit:** I just stubbed out some code for this below. Disclaimer: this hasn't been tested or even compiled, this is just me in Notepad++. I'll attempt to test when I get some more free time, but it *should* accomplish what you're looking for. Obviously you'd want to keep your trigger simple and move this logic into a helper class.

```
trigger ContentVersionTrigger on ContentVersion (after insert) {

    Set<Schema.SObjectType> objsPreventImageFiles = new Set<Schema.SObjectType>{
        Account.SObjectType
    };
    Set<String> imageTypes = new Set<String>{'bmp', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'png'};  // the list goes on...

    // determine which files we're interested in (images), so we don't unnecessarily query ContentDocumentLink
    Set<Id> contentDocIds = new Set<Id>();
    List<ContentVersion> images = new List<ContentVersion>();
    for ( ContentVersion cv : Trigger.new ) {
        // have to use PathOnClient, since FileExtension field doesn't seem to be populated in this context
        if ( imageTypes.contains(Utils.getFileExtension(cv.PathOnClient)) ) {
            images.add(cv);
            contentDocIds.add(cv.ContentDocumentId);
        }
    }

    if ( !images.isEmpty() ) {
        // query ContentDocumentLink and build a map of ContentDocumentId -> CDL, which will allow us to determine the parent object type
        Map<Id, List<ContentDocumentLink>> contentDocToLinks = new Map<Id, List<ContentDocumentLink>>();
        for ( ContentDocumentLink cdl : [select Id, ContentDocumentId, LinkedEntityId from ContentDocumentLink where ContentDocumentId in :contentDocIds] ) {
            if ( !contentDocToLinks.containsKey(cdl.ContentDocumentId) ) {
                contentDocToLinks.put(cdl.ContentDocumentId, new List<ContentDocumentLink>());
            }
            contentDocToLinks.get(cdl.ContentDocumentId).add(cdl);
        }

        // loop back through our images and determine which are linked to forbidden objects
        for ( ContentVersion cv : images ) {
            List<ContentDocumentLink> cdls = contentDocToLinks.get(cv.ContentDocumentId);
            if ( cdls != null ) {
                for ( ContentDocumentLink cdl : cdls ) {
                    // use the nifty Id.getSObjectType() field to determine if the image File is linked to an object we don't want users associating with
                    if ( cdl.LinkedEntityId != null && objsPreventImageFiles.contains(cdl.LinkedEntityId.getSObjectType()) ) {
                        cv.addError('You cannot upload an image File associated with this object (' + cdl.LinkedEntityId.getSObjectType() + ')');
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

public class Utils {
    public static String getFileExtension(String filename) {
        String ext = '';
        if ( filename != null ) {
            List<String> splits = filename.split('\\.');
            ext = splits.get(splits.size()-1);
        }
        return ext.toLowerCase();
    }
}
```

Comment: Learned a lot from this so +1 from me.

Comment: Thanks JCD, When I do attach a file in Account Object it gets attached because this is a after insert trigger and I changed it to before insert den I got this error " Implementation restriction: ContentDocumentLink requires a filter by a single Id on ContentDocumentId or LinkedEntityId using the equals operator or multiple Id's using the IN operator.: Trigger.ContentVersionTrigger: line 22, column 1"." I found Two LinkedEntityIds on a same field (1 is User Id another is related Object Id) I could not specify the exact Id here.

Comment: Your `ContentDocumentId` will be null in the before insert trigger on that object, so the query on that record (which requires a filter) throws the error you're seeing. While you can still prevent the insert of a record in an after insert trigger, I did some digging in the debug logs and it looks like the second `ContentDocumentLink` record isn't available in the context. It must be inserted at some point after the `ContentVersion` record is inserted. I'll play around with it a bit more when I can; I may need to move the trigger logic to the `ContentDocumentLink` object as a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

When the `Attachment` object is inserted after uploading via a browser, its `ContentType` field will have a value of "image/png" or "image/jpeg" so you can call [addError](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_addError) from your trigger to block the insert. I do not know, but presume that this error is presented appropriately in Lightning Experience.

(See e.g. [The Complete List of MIME Types](http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/mime-types-complete-list/) for more possible values.)

**PS**

From [Files and Content: What’s Not in Lightning Experience](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=lex_gaps_limitations_files_and_content.htm&language=en_US):

> Files and attachments are two different types of objects, and always
>   have been. Unlike files, attachments are associated only with a
>   particular record and can’t be shared further. In Lightning
>   Experience, uploads to the Notes & Attachments related list are files.
>   In Salesforce Classic prior to Spring ’16, uploads to this related
>   list were always attachments instead of files. For existing orgs, this
>   means that the Notes & Attachments list can contain a mix of
>   attachments that were uploaded in Salesforce Classic and files added
>   in Lightning Experience.

Personally I'm unclear on what you can and can't do with a file - hopefully someone else can tell you.

Comment: Hi keith, Wen it comes to Lightning Experience the trigger on attachment doens'nt support.

Comment: @KartiK OK, but triggers still exist in Lightning Experience as they are in the database layer. What specifically doesn't work?

Comment: attachment object is not a separate object in Lex, the same trigger on attachment will work wen you attach a file from classic window but does'nt triggered while attaching a file in Lex window. for example following works works on classic layout but noy in Lightning Experience====== trigger AttachmentTriggerDemo on Attachment (before insert) {
 for(Attachment att: Trigger.new){
        if(att.ContentType=='image/png'){
           Trigger.new[0].addError('You Cannot upload PNG files');
        }
    }
}

Comment: @KartiK I now understand. Hopefully someone can answer.